# Javascript set time string to date object

Tags: javascript, time

Please see the below code;

```
var d = new Date();
var s = "01.00 AM";
d.setTime(s);
```

I know this code is wrong. Please give me the correct way to set the time. I have 12 hour time in string format in my hand.

**The time will vary. Cannot know what will be the time earlier. Also it is 12 hour time. So it will be AM or PM**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can parse the time with a regex, and set the hours and minutes accordingly:

http://jsfiddle.net/54VkC/1/

```
var d = new Date(),
    s = "01.25 PM",
    parts = s.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+) (\w+)/),
    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 12,
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

d.setHours(hours);
d.setMinutes(minutes);

alert(d);
```

***Edit 1:***
As jaisonDavis pointed out, the original code will not work for AM or PM for 12.XX, which was an oversight since I never use 12-hour format myself, thinking it started at 00.00 which was wrong.

The corrected code which handles these cases can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/54VkC/93/

```js
var test, parts, hours, minutes, date,
    d = (new Date()).getTime(),
    tests = ['01.25 PM', '11.35 PM', '12.45 PM', '01.25 AM', '11.35 AM', '12.45 AM'],
    i = tests.length,
    timeReg = /(\d+)\.(\d+) (\w+)/;

for(; i-- > 0;) {
    test = tests[i];
    
    parts = test.match(timeReg);
    
    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ?
        function(am) {return am < 12 ? am : 0}(parseInt(parts[1], 10)) :
        function(pm) {return pm < 12 ? pm + 12 : 12}(parseInt(parts[1], 10));
    
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    
    date = new Date(d);
    
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    
    console.log(test + ' => ' + date);
}
```

Comment: If the time is between 12.00 PM and 12.59 PM it still adds 12 hours to the time, which makes the time 12.** AM

Comment: @jaisonDavis You are right, thank you for catching it, I don't really use 12-hour format myself. I have made an addition to the original answer, which handles these cases. And I will be sure to remember 12.XX when I work with 12-hour format in the future :-)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.. thank you!!

Answer (score 15):

I'm late to the party, but I thought I'd share a funtion that doesn't use regex:

```
function setDateTime(date, time) {
    var index = time.indexOf("."); // replace with ":" for differently displayed time.
    var index2 = time.indexOf(" ");

    var hours = time.substring(0, index);
    var minutes = time.substring(index + 1, index2);

    var mer = time.substring(index2 + 1, time.length);
    if (mer == "PM"){
        hours = hours + 12;
    }


    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    date.setSeconds("00");

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) will be the easy solution.

```
const fullDate = new Date();
// fullDate = Tue Dec 12 2017 11:18:30 GMT+0530 (IST) {}
const time = '01.00 AM';
const d = moment(fullDate).format('L'); // d = "12/12/2017"
const date = moment(d +' '+ time).format();
// date = "2017-12-12T01:00:00+05:30"
```

If you want convert moment date to js date

```
const jsDate = moment(date).toDate();
```

Comment: Why will it be 'best'?

Comment: I highly doubt this is the 'best' solution, pushing the user to bring in a huge third-party library for such a simple functionality should be expressed with great caution.

Comment: well I change my word from 'best' to 'easy'

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCurrentDate() {
    var lDate = new Date();
    var lDay = lDate.getDate();
    var lMonth = lDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var lYear = lDate.getFullYear();

    if (lDay < 10) {
        lDay = '0' + lDay
    }

    if (lMonth < 10) {
        lMonth = '0' + lMonth
    }
    mCurrentDate = lYear + "-" + lMonth + "-" + lDay + "T00:00:00+05:30";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a few things as an improvement to the accepted answer by @thebreiflabb to suit my use case and thought i'd share.

if the regex is changed to `timeReg = /(\d+)[\.|:](\d+)\s?(\w+)/;`,
it'll handle a few other common cases.

namely:

- using a colon instead of decimal point between hours and minutes
- allowing am/pm to immediately follow the time with no space

also, setting the seconds to 0 (since that was my main use case)

the resulting code would be:

```
var test, parts, hours, minutes, date,
    d = (new Date()).getTime(),
    tests = ['01.25 PM', '01:25pm', '1:25 PM', '11.35 PM', '12.45 PM', '01.25 AM', '11.35 AM', '12.45 AM'],
    i = tests.length,
    timeReg = /(\d+)[\.|:](\d+)\s?(\w+)/;

for(; i-- > 0;) {
    test = tests[i];

    parts = test.match(timeReg);

    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ?
        function(am) {return am < 12 ? am : 0}(parseInt(parts[1], 10)) :
        function(pm) {return pm < 12 ? pm + 12 : 12}(parseInt(parts[1], 10));

    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

    date = new Date(d);

    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    date.setSeconds(0);

    console.log(test + ' => ' + date);
}
```