# How to convert string to Time with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, time, converters

I have Lable, ID = label1 on file .aspx
I have file .js.
I want to Convert user input in lable1 to Time and then Compere it with current time

```
<input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker_7" />
```

above is my code on .aspx.
the value is like

> 10:15 PM

How do I call label1 on .js file ?

How do I compare the value on label1 and current time ?

Comment: give the label and sample value of that text

Comment: here is what you want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382266/javascript-set-time-string-to-date-object

Comment: You need to create a Date object (e.g. `new Date()`), then make a copy, then set the time of one of those dates to the time in the input, then compare the two dates. What does the time value look like?

Comment: "10:30 PM" the value of label1.