# How to convert a time string to Date object on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this - "05:21 PM" . How do I convert it to a date object in current time zone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382266/javascript-set-time-string-to-date-object

Comment: @IlyaZinkevych thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.........

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(15);
d.setMinutes(15);

toLocalTime(d.getTime())
```

.........

```
/**
 * Converts CDT time to your browser local time.
 * @param time
 * @returns
 */
function toLocalTime(time) {
    if (time <= 0)
        return '';

    var m = moment.tz(time, 'America/Chicago'); //CDT

    var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client

    m.tz(tz.name()); // Convert CDT to local time

    return m.format('HH:mm:ss');
}
```