# Sunrise Alarm Clock - Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

My friend got a "sunrise alarm clock" which when it's time to wake up becomes brighter to simulate a sunrise to ease waking up.

I thought I could do the same with my laptop, however I've been struggling with getting Javascript time to work. I'd appreciate any help in getting this thing to work.

I've been trying to add to the minutes value (wakeupM) however long I wanted to sleep, this would delay the setTimeout function and only run when I was going to wake up. Nevertheless, I would want to be able to set the time in the time input box and for the "sunrise" feature to only run when it hits that time.

Thank you for the help in advance!

```js
var countTime;

function mySleep() {
  var now = new Date();
  var nowM = now.getMinutes();


  var wakeup = new Date();
  var wakeupM = wakeup.getMinutes() + 3;


  var timeDif = wakeupM - nowM;
  countTime = 6000 * timeDif;


  document.getElementById("settime").innerHTML = countTime;

}

function mySunrise() {
  var colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'white'];
  var active = 0;


  setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
  }, 3000);;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
  /* initial color */
  transition: background 5s;
  /* .5s how long transition should take */
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="myTime" value="22:15:00">
<button onclick="setTimeout(mySunrise, countTime); mySleep();">Wake me up</button>
<h1>waking you up at:</h1>
<p id="settime"></p>
```

Comment: Your `countTime` variable is used before initialization..

Comment: @ammarx how can I call the countTime variable after mySleep runs but still include it in the setTimeout function?

Comment: You should compute `countTime` before using it. Maybe you should do that outside your sleep function by adding an event listener that calculates `countTime` every time the input field changes. Moreover, your calculation of `countTime` inside the sleep function is not based on the value set by the user using the input field.

Comment: @ammarx I reversed the order of onclick to "mySleep(); setTimeout(mySunrise, countTime); and now the delay part works - I am struggling with using the input box because I don't know how to convert the hours and minutes in the box to a timestamp that will allow the mySleep function to calculate the difference in milliseconds for the delay to work

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382266/javascript-set-time-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 0):

Finished version on **my personal website** - http://piotrirving.com/alarm/sunrise.html

```js
var wakeupH;
var wakeupM;
var wakeupS;

var nowH;
var nowM;
var nowS;


function mySleep() {
  var wakeUpTime = document.getElementById("myTime");
  var currentVal = wakeUpTime.value;
  var res = currentVal.split(":");

  wakeupH = res[0]
  wakeupM = res[1]
  wakeupS = res[2]

  var now = new Date();
  var nowH = now.getHours();
  var nowM = now.getMinutes();
  var nowS = now.getSeconds();

  var date1 = new Date(2000, 0, 1, nowH, nowM, nowS);

  var date2 = new Date(2000, 0, 1, wakeupH, wakeupM, 1);


  if (date2 < date1) {
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
  }

  countTime = date2 - date1;
  document.getElementById("settime").innerHTML = countTime;
}



function mySunrise() {
  var colors = ["#BDB76B", "#F0E68C", "#EEE8AA", "#FFDAB9", "#FFE4B5", "#FFA07A", "#FF7F50", "#FF6347", "#FF4500", "#FF8C00", "#FFA500", "#FFEFD5", "#FAFAD2", "#FFFACD", "#FFFFE0", "#FFFF00", "#FFD700", "white"];
  var active = 0;


  setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
  }, 3000);;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  /* initial color */
  transition: background 30s;
  /* .5s how long transition should take */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
Time: <input type="time" id="myTime" value="22:53:01">
<button onclick="mySleep(); setTimeout(mySunrise, countTime);">Wake me up</button>
<p id="settime"></p>
```

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for the heads up, I've added that this is a link to my personal website - I just wanted to show the final product